# How to get those subcategories to show on main categories?

Tags: python, django

I'm very new to django and I'm making a ecommerce website. I'm trying to have subcategories for my products so I assigned each product with subcategories and the subcategory have parent_category. However I'm have trouble getting all products of the parent category to show. Can you help me out please

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name             = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug             = models.SlugField(unique = True)
    parent_category  = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

```
def list_of_post_by_category(request,category_slug):
    maincat = []
    subcat = []
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    obj = Product_info.objects.filter()
    if category_slug:
        category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
        obj = obj.filter(category=category)
    for c in categories:
        if c.parent_category == None:
            maincat.append(c)
        elif c.parent_category == category:
            subcat.append(c)
    context = {"category":maincat,"subcategory":subcat,"obj_list":obj,"showcat":category}
    return render(request,'cat.html',context)
```

Comment: Can you post your cat.html file as well please?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built in ORM to filter for the correct categories. This will increase performance, because you will only retrieve the relevant categories for the current page.

There are some other issues with your code though:

- When there is no category_slug defined, the statement `elif c.parent_category == category:` will not work as intended, since category is undefined. You probably want subcat to be an empty list in that case.
- Your variable names are not very verbose. It is not really clear what kind of class `obj` is an instance of, and from their names, it's not clear that maincat and subcat are lists.

```
def list_of_post_by_category(request,category_slug):

    product_info_list = Product_info.objects.all()
    sub_categories = []

    if category_slug:
        category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
        product_info_list = product_info.filter(category=category)
        sub_categories = Category.objects.filter(parent_category = category)

    main_categories = Category.objects.filter(parent_category__isnull = True)

    context = {
                 "category" : main_categories,
                 "subcategory" : sub_categories,
                 "obj_list" : product_info_list,
                 "showcat" : category
               }

    return render(request,'cat.html',context)
```

One other thing I'd recommend is that you change the name of the `Product_info` class to ProductInfo, [according to the PEP-8 styleguide.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names)